# Bitbucket daily personal log

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I've been using Bitbucket for a week now. It seems like a capable platform. Personally in my development activities, I keep a daily "journal" of whatever I need to keep track of separately from any commits to the Git repo. It gives me a place to keep all my "thoughts and ideas" in one place.

Before I end a day's work, or I jot down what I last worked on and any thoughts I think I'll need on the following day. And before I begin each day's work, I just flip to the last page of my journal and it quickly brings me back up to speed of where I was at yesterday, no matter how little sleep I got.  :-)

I see Bitbucket has "Comments", "Work Log", "History" and "Activity", but they seem to be tied only to user stories, todos and the like.

Does anyone know of a way where I can have something like a "Work Log" tied directly to my user account? I'm thinking I could use it for my personal "Journal".

Note: I'm using a locally installed Bitbucket server.

Comment: I should add, presently I've just created an "Epic" tied to each project, assigned it to myself, and I never close the epic. I keep all my "Journal" notes there. But, it'd be nice if there were a way to keep my journal directly tied to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the online https://bitbucket.org (not specified in the question) rather than a hosted instance then you can do a couple of things.

## 1 Wiki

1. Create a repository which will act as your work log

   - Obviously if you want to keep notes with the same code base just enable the wiki for that repository. The question seemed to suggest you may want to be repository/project agnostic
2. Update the settings of the repository to enable a private or public wiki

This is probably the simplest and richest replacement to your note pad

## 2 Use a repository

1. Create a repository which will act as your work log
2. commit Markdown (i.e `readme.md` or `index.md`) files

**Note:** in the case of a hosted instance this could even be a repository associated to your user rather than a project.

This is very manual, though it does mean you can have an offline version of your "pad" that you can edit/search in your IDE with some IDE autocomplete. Just like the wiki you can use the code backtick escapes with syntax highlighting. Last I checked the these were rendered pretty well in the browser through bitbucket.org as well as any editor/IDE you might use.

## Regarding todo's

I've found the best cheap todo solution for me is using a gist as described on [life hacker](http://lifehacker.com/why-a-github-gist-is-my-favorite-to-do-list-1493063613). They are low ceremony and versioned which checks all my boxes (excuse the pun). If you couple that with the above you may actually be able to embed it into your bitbucket wiki, though I've not tried.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate I'm using a locally installed version of Bitbucket. I like your idea of using a Wiki page. Maybe there's a plugin or something I could install to bring the Wiki page functionality to the locally installed version?

Comment: @MikeyE Not sure about plugins. I think for a locally hosted instance you're left with getting confluence to act as your wiki, or committing markdown files to a repository. I've actually committed markdown in a repo at a company that didn't have a good wiki and it worked pretty well. The GitLab instance even allowed me to edit the markdown in the browser, bitbucket may allow the same.

Comment: @MikeyE - I'm interested, but this question seems to have died. Did you come up with a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JIRA and Bitbucket already, maybe consider Confluence? Confluence has some convenient and easy to manage TODO functionality and it lets you expand on those thoughts with all the power of a wiki when you are done.

I keep a "TODO" page and additionally put the checkbox on any tasks in other pages. They are all aggregated together in a tasks view.

See:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf54/confluence-user-s-guide/managing-changes-and-notifications-and-tasks/managing-tasks-in-confluence